# how to write cakephp and and or query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

```
 $tmp_sales    = $this->tmp_sale->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    array(
                        'no' => $no,
                        'barcode' => $barcode,'employee' => $emp, 'store' => $store_name
                    )
                )
            ));
```

This is my present query.

```
select * from tmp_sale where  no = '$no' and 
                       'employee' ='$emp' and  store = '$store_name' and ( barcode='$barcode' or name='$barcode')
```

I want to make change like above . how to write query like this in cakephp

Comment: Read the manual, it is explained there including examples: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Answer (score 1):

```
'conditions' => array(
    'no' => $no,
    'employee' => $emp,
    'store '=> $store_name,
    'OR' => array(
        array('barcode' => $barcode),
        array('name' => $barcode)
    )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

> **Cakephp Model name should be Singular,`tmp_sale` Model name should be replaced by `TmpSale` name. The query of cakephp shown in below.
>   You should try this**

```
 $tmp_sales = $this->TmpSale->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array( 'no' => $no,
                    'employee' => $emp,
                    'store '=>$store_name,
                    'or'=>array('barcode'=>$barcode,
                        'name'=>$barcode)

            )
        ));
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey buddy , you **Dont** need 2 arrays in conditions , 1st is sufficient .  `'conditions' => array(array(.....`       Should be converted to `'conditions' => array(....)`

Comment: This query is proper working, if you have a query you just answer,

Comment: Why you need 2 array nested in condition ? Isnt 1 array sufficient ?